# UILocalNotification Schehduling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have Scheduled my local notification to fire at 4.00 pm and want that notification daily at 4.00 pm but the notification fires before time at 3.44 pm , 3.47 pm etc.

here is the code -

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[dateComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComponents setSecond:0.0];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How are you feeling?"];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Try setting second to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date]; // Set your time here
myDate = [myDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:1*24*60*60];
UILocalNotification  *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.fireDate = myDate;
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How are you feeling?"];
notif.alertBody = @"Reminder is set";
notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Hope it will help you.